# Apache reverse proxy rewrite get url

Tags: apache-2.4

I have a intranet server which isnt reachable from the public. Also i have a Server where a Apache reverse proxy is running.

**Intranet: intranet.domain.com**
**Reverse Proxy: external.domain.com**

This is my Config

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName       external.domain.com
    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/reverseproxy-error-log
    CustomLog /var/log/apache2/reverseproxy-access-_log combined
    LogLevel          warn
    AddDefaultCharset utf-8
   
  
      SSLEngine On
      SSLProxyEngine On
      SSLProxyVerify none
      SSLProxyCheckPeerCN off
      SSLProxyCheckPeerName off
      ProxyRequests Off
      ProxyPreserveHost On
  
       <Proxy *>
         Require all granted
       </Proxy>
  
    Forwarding Intranet to external
          ProxyPass / https://intranet.domain.com/
          ProxyPassReverse / https://intranet.domain.com/
  
       ProxyErrorOverride Off
  </VirtualHost>
```

I have deleted the part where i set the SSL certificate etc. as thats not the problem

When i now load external.domain.com the site is loading but all of the pictures and css isnt loaded because its loaded from intranet.domain.com and so i get 404.

As an example this is a GET request i see.

```
scheme
    https
host
    intranet.domain.com
filename
    /fileadmin/user_upload/Admin/Header/Header_Telefon.jpg
```

So my question is now how can i rewrite that request so the host is **external.domain.com** instead of **intranet.domain.com**

Because when i try this url https://external.domain.com/fileadmin/user_upload/Admin/Header/Header_Telefon.jpg i can see that image without any problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to configure the application that runs on internal.domain.com, to that it produces either only relative URL's, or URL's using the domain external.domain.com.  Apach's proxypassreverse can't change URL's inside response bodies.

Comment: Found the solution like 2 hours ago. Youre completly right ! 

The server is running Typo3 and it had 
`config.baseURL= http://<domain>/` activated. 

I changed it to 
`config.absRefPrefix = /`. 

Now everything is working just fine :) Thank you very much !